# Getting error while executing SOAP API Url

Tags: php, wsdl, centos7, soap-client, php-ini

After executing the following URL from `SOAP API` concept, getting error of `WSDL`.

**URL**: `http://139.5.19.140:7047/DynamicsNAV71/WS/B.%20Jain%20Pharma-2017/Codeunit/customer`

I getting a common error of WSDL : 
`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://139.5.19.140:7047/DynamicsNAV71/WS/B.%20Jain%20Pharma-2017/Codeunit/customer' : Document is empty in /home/Useracbglm9a/public_html/nav_con/php_nav_lib/Navision.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /home/Useracbglm9a/public_html/nav_con/php_nav_lib/Navision.php(11): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://139.5.19...', Array) #1 /home/Useracbglm9a/public_html/nav_con/my_customer.php(135): NTLMSoapClient->__construct('http://139.5.19...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/axbl3cbglm9a/public_html/nav_con/php_nav_lib/Navision.php on line 11`

After Researching for this error i got that mainly this problem is of `openssl` extension of PHP. 
I'm using PHP version: 7.1 with `centOS 7.0` 
But i didn't get this extension of `openssl` in `phpIniEditor`.

Now i got confused that what exactly the problem is.!!!

Please Help & require your valuable support and feedback. Thanks in advance. Your Support is really appreciable.

---